# Stop CSS styles changing after a certain resolution - media query?

Tags: html, css

If the user reduces the browser window below a certain resolution, say 320 width, I dont want any further css layout changes to take effect. Basically what ever the layout is at 320, I don't want to change this any further, it should just hold the 320 view.

Would I use a fixed width with a media query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) is exactly what would fulfill this purpose.  Specifically:

```
<style>
  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    body {
      width: 320px;
    }
  }
</style>
```

And here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L23xS/)